# Copy and Paste Formats in Visual Studio 2012 SSRS Reporting Services

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I'm modifying an existing SSRS report in Visual Studio 2012.  I want to copy the formats from one textbox, and paste the format onto another textbox.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this, even with an online search.

Can Visual Studio do something like this?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so from the properties of the textbox. Select the textbox to copy the format from, press `F4`. In the Properties pane, look for `Format` under `Number`. You can copy the format and paste it in the same `Format` property of the other textbox. Here is a snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BhupeshC.  I was looking more for something like copy and paste formats like you can do in excel.  I don't think this is available in Reporting Services.